# JSF returns blank/unparsed page with plain/raw XHTML/XML/EL source instead of rendered HTML output

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el, facelets

I have some Facelets files like below.

```
WebContent
 |-- index.xhtml
 |-- register.xhtml
 |-- templates
 |    |--userForm.xhtml
 |    `--banner.xhtml
 :
```

Both pages are using templates from `/templates` directory. My `/index.xhtml` opens fine in browser. I get the generated HTML output. I have a link in `/index.xhtml` file to `/register.xhtml` file.

However, my `/register.xhtml` is not getting parsed and returns as plain XHTML / raw XML instead of its generated HTML output. All EL expressions in form of `#{...}` are displayed as-is instead of that their results are being printed. When I rightclick page in browser and do *View page source*, then I still see the original XHTML source code instead of the generated HTML output. For example, the `<h:body>` did not become a `<body>`. It looks like that the template is not being executed.

However, when I open the `/register.xhtml` like `/faces/register.xhtml` in browser's address bar, then it displays correctly. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There are three main causes.

1. `FacesServlet` is not invoked.
2. XML namespace URIs are missing or wrong.
3. Multiple JSF implemenations have been loaded.

---

### 1. Make sure that URL matches `FacesServlet` mapping

The URL of the link (the URL as you see in browser's address bar) has to match the `<url-pattern>` of the `FacesServlet` as definied in `web.xml` in order to get all the JSF works to run. The `FacesServlet` is the one responsible for parsing the XHTML file, collecting submitted form values, performing conversion/validation, updating models, invoking actions and generating HTML output. If you don't invoke the `FacesServlet` by URL, then all you would get (and see via rightclick, *View Source* in browser) is indeed the raw XHTML source code.

If the `<url-pattern>` is for example `*.jsf`, then the link should point to `/register.jsf` and not `/register.xhtml`. If it's for example `/faces/*`, like you have, then the link should point to `/faces/register.xhtml` and not `/register.xhtml`. One way to avoid this confusion is to just change the `<url-pattern>` from `/faces/*` to `*.xhtml`. The below is thus the ideal mapping:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you can't change the `<url-pattern>` to `*.xhtml` for some reason, then you probably would also like to prevent endusers from directly accessing XHTML source code files by URL. In that case you can add a `<security-constraint>` on the `<url-pattern>` of `*.xhtml` with an empty `<auth-constraint>` in `web.xml` which prevents that:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Restrict direct access to XHTML files</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>XHTML files</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

JSF 2.3 which was introduced April 2017 has already solved all of above by automatically registering the `FacesServlet` on an URL pattern of `*.xhtml` during webapp's startup. The alternative is thus to simply upgrade to latest available JSF version which should be JSF 2.3 or higher. But ideally you should still explicitly register the `FacesServlet` on only one URL pattern of `*.xhtml` because having multiple possible URLs for exactly the same resource like `/register.xhtml`, `/register.jsf`, `/register.faces` and `/faces/register.xhtml` is bad for SEO.

#### See also:

- [Set default home page via <welcome-file> in JSF project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27562813/set-default-home-page-via-welcome-file-in-eclipse-jsf-project-which-can-be-run)
- [Opening JSF Facelets page shows "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804452/opening-facelets-page-errors-with-this-xml-file-does-not-appear-to-have-any-sty)
- [Sometimes I see JSF URL is *.jsf, sometimes *.xhtml and sometimes /faces/*. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why)
- [JavaServer Faces 2.2 and HTML5 support, why is XHTML still being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189372/javaserver-faces-2-2-and-html5-support-why-is-xhtml-still-being-used)
- [Which XHTML files do I need to put in /WEB-INF and which not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031811/which-xhtml-files-do-i-need-to-put-in-web-inf-and-which-not)
- [Our servlets wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - to learn the mandatory basics about servlets

---

### 2. Make sure that XML namespaces match JSF version

Another probable cause is that XML namespaces don't match the JSF version. The `xmlns.jcp.org` like below is new since JSF 2.2 and do not work in older JSF versions. The symptoms are almost the same as if the `FacesServlet` is not invoked.

```
<html lang="en"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
```

The `jakarta.faces` namespace URIs like below is new since Faces 4.0 and do not work in older JSF/Faces versions.

```
<html lang="en"
    xmlns:f="jakarta.faces.core"
    xmlns:h="jakarta.faces.html"
    xmlns:ui="jakarta.faces.facelets">
```

If you can't upgrade to JSF 2.2 or higher, then you need to use the old `java.sun.com` XML namespaces instead:

```
<html lang="en"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
```

But ideally you should always use the latest version where available.

#### See also:

- [What are the namespaces for "h", "f", ... in a JSF page for Jakarta EE 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68438669/what-are-the-namespaces-for-h-f-in-a-jsf-page-for-jakarta-ee-9)
- [JSF tags not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942868/jsf-tags-not-executed/)
- [Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/XXX declared with prefix XXX but no taglibrary exists for that namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30849150/warning-this-page-calls-for-xml-namespace-http-xmlns-jcp-org-jsf-xxx-declared/)

---

### 3. Multiple JSF implementations have been loaded

One more probable cause is that multiple JSF implementations have been loaded by your webapp, conflicting and corrupting each other. For example, when your webapp's runtime classpath is polluted with multiple different versioned JSF libraries, or in the specific Mojarra 2.x + Tomcat 8.x combination, when there's an unnecessary `ConfigureListener` entry in webapp's `web.xml` causing it to be loaded twice.

```
<!-- You MUST remove this one from web.xml! -->
<!-- This is actually a workaround for buggy GlassFish3 and Jetty servers. -->
<!-- When leaving this in and you're targeting Tomcat, you'll run into trouble. -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

When using Maven, make absolutely sure that you declare the dependencies the right way and that you understand dependency scopes. Importantingly, do not bundle dependencies in webapp when those are already provided by the target server.

#### See also:

- [Configuration of com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264083/configuration-of-com-sun-faces-config-configurelistener)
- [How to properly install and configure JSF libraries via Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081234/how-to-properly-install-and-configure-jsf-libraries-via-maven)

---

### Make sure that you learn JSF the right way

JSF has a very steep learning curve for those unfamiliar with basic [HTTP](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-the-protocol-every-web-developer-must-know-part-1--net-31177), [HTML](http://htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/) and [Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452). There are a lot of low quality resources on the Internet. Please ignore code snippet scraping sites maintained by amateurs with primary focus on advertisement income instead of on teaching, such as roseindia, tutorialspoint, javabeat, baeldung, etc. They are easily recognizable by disturbing advertising links/banners. Also please ignore resources dealing with jurassic JSF 1.x. They are easily recognizable by using JSP files instead of XHTML files. JSP as view technology was deprecated since JSF 2.0 at 2009 already.

To get started the right way, start at [our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) and order an [authoritative book](https://www.amazon.com/s?field-keywords=java+faces). At my blog you can also find a super clear and detailed JSF tutorial: [JSF 2.3 tutorial with Eclipse, Maven, WildFly and H2](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2020/04/jsf-23-tutorial-with-eclipse-maven.html) which should at least be helpful to get started from absolute zero.

#### See also:

- [Java / Jakarta EE web development, where do I start and what skills do I need?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958808/java-ee-web-development-where-do-i-start-and-what-skills-do-i-need)
- [What is the need of JSF, when UI can be achieved with JavaScript libraries such as jQuery and AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421839/what-is-the-need-of-jsf-when-ui-can-be-achieved-from-css-html-javascript-jqu)

Comment: THanks BalusC. I will try this out and back to you. Keep in touch.

Comment: Hi dear,
Now I added my link using <h:link /> tag. The links work fine. Still I have one question. The link is automatically go into /faces/register.xhtml . Is there any way that I can hide the /faces/ directory and link should displayed /register.xhtml without the "faces" directory???

Comment: Ah, you're using prefix mapping `/faces/*`, no you can't hide it. Use extension mapping like `*.jsf`, `*.faces` or even `*.customextension`.

Comment: Replace `/faces/*` by `*.jsf` as `url-pattern` of `FacesServlet`.

Comment: Just now had another option. p:remoteCommand had an update attribute with wrong id. Maybe, it will work out for somebody.

Comment: I'm 100% sure there is a related question of jsf tags not being rendered in 404 pages if not used correctly. Cannot seem to find it. Want to mark a question a duplicate of this 'lost' question

Comment: @Kukeltje: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2998576 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/25644513 maybe?

Comment: Saved my day, sorry saved my night and that too Friday night, if we will ever met then I will buy you a beer, if you drink :)