# JSF tags not processed

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, jsf-2, maven-gae-plugin

I'm trying to run a jsf 2.1 / spring 3.1 app on google app engine. It all starts up fine (on development server) without any exceptions.

But every page I access, the jsf-tags are not processed.

- On pages without templates, all HTML is rendered. jsf-tags are visible in sourcecode.
- On pages with templates, the browser shows the plain xhtml with the hint, that no layout information is available, this makes sense to me, because only the  part is sent to the browser.

Seems to me, that JSF isn't working at all. Althought JSF seems to be initalized correctly.

I'm using maven-gae-plugin version 0.9.2 since I was not able to deploy my app to the development server with the latest release 0.9.5.

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>

    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- GAE Bug 1506 JSP 2.1 API but 2.0 Implementation -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.validateXml</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableThreading</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>


  <!-- Add Support for Spring -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

   <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

<!-- Welcome page -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list> 

   <!-- JSF Mapping -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" >

    <h:body>

        <h1>JSF 2.0 + Spring Example</h1>

    <h:link value="Register" outcome="register" />

    <h2>TEST</h2>

    </h:body>

</html>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>
                org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
    </application>

</faces-config>
```

Regards.

Comment: Your configuration seems fine. I think you have a problem with url-patterns. What does calling index.jsf outputs in your case?

Comment: using http://localhost:8080/index.jsf causes the following Exception:
`com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException: /index.jsf/index.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:231)`

using url http://localhost:8080 causes a NPE here:
`at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.loggingGetPhaseMapForReading(ELFlash.java:793)`

Comment: Some update on this. I changed the url-pattern to "/*.xhtml". Adding this /, the NPE does no longer occur when calling http://localhost:8080 (I'm now redirected to the welcome-file), but my main issue, the jsf is still not rendered.

Comment: I have a slightly different configuration  `<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>` Copied your index.html as test.xhtml in my configuration and both http://localhost:8080/faces/test.xhtml and http://localhost:8080/test.jsf works for me. Wish I could help

Comment: I modified my configuration to match yours. The problem didn't disappear. JSF is still not rendered...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSF returns blank/unparsed page with plain/raw XHTML/XML/EL source instead of rendered HTML output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112946/jsf-returns-blank-unparsed-page-with-plain-raw-xhtml-xml-el-source-instead-of-re)