# What does "This XML file does not appear to have any style information". mean?

Tags: error-handling

I know very little of xml, almost nothing and now I've to deal with a website which allows me to upload any kind of file, but when I visit the link that points to that file I see this message

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>56D9E6D5AB81C7F8</RequestId>
<HostId>
bbhO3UnotoXA8qS8aMbKHhPdjGIwegs6dfX5cPJ7yZS7hRaDTuacjPhaPY4WH/vYXuOBfgCm23o=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

This means that the server is proposing content as xml but if I upload an xml file, the server will give me the same message. But actually what I don't understand is what's that "AccessDenied"... I don't know where I can start to understand considering that I don't have access to that server.
Now I would like to know what is happening exactly, what's the logic behind all this?

Answer (score 4):

I faced this very error when trying to access a file from AWS's S3 bucket. Turns out, I just had to make that file public. (Though keep in mind, making a file public comes with obvious security risks)

Answer (score 2):

> You will get this error in the client side when the client (the webbrowser) for some reason interprets the HTTP response content as `text/xml` instead of `text/html` and the parsed XML tree doesn't have any `XML-stylesheet`.

[Opening Facelets page errors with "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804452/opening-facelets-page-errors-with-this-xml-file-does-not-appear-to-have-any-sty)

Comment: I already read that answer and in fact the server is forcing somehow the browser to render that file as text/xml. But so why if I give an xml file to it, the server response is the same?

Comment: how exactly do you give xml to server? do you use some upload form?

Comment: Yes, I use an upload form and after I take the direct link to the file that continues to have the same .xml extension