# How to get rid of <partial-response> XML plain to browser using JSF

Tags: ajax, jsf, spring-security, exception, partial-response

I am Using JSF 2.0 with primefaces5.0 by using spring framework but i think the problem is related to JSF , i have many different applications but some times clicking on any application giving me  with plain html along with message that "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below." but on Refreshing the page application open normally without any error.

```
  <partial-response id="j_id1">
     <changes>
<update id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45">
<![CDATA[
<tr class="ui-expanded-row-content ui-widget-content"><td colspan="8"><table id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt72" class="ui-panelgrid ui-widget" role="grid"><thead class="ui-panelgrid-header"><tr class="ui-widget-header" role="row"><td colspan="4" role="columnheader"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt73" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">View RetClients</label></td></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="ui-widget-content" role="row"><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt74" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">Num. Cliente</label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt75" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"></label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt76" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">Nome</label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt77" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"></label></td></tr><tr class="ui-widget-content" role="row"><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt78" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">CPF</label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt79" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"></label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt80" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">RG:</label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt81" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"></label></td></tr><tr class="ui-widget-content" role="row"><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt82" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">Birth Date</label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt83" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"></label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt84" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">Last Modification Date</label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt85" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"></label></td></tr><tr class="ui-widget-content" role="row"><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt86" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">Date de Cadastro</label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt87" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"></label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt88" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">Nome do Pai</label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt89" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"></label></td></tr><tr class="ui-widget-content" role="row"><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt90" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">Establecimento</label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt91" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"></label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt92" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">Mobile Num</label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt93" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"></label></td></tr><tr class="ui-widget-content" role="row"><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt94" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">Email ID</label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt95" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"></label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt96" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">Marital Status</label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt97" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"></label></td></tr><tr class="ui-widget-content" role="row"><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt98" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">Telephone</label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt99" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"></label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt100" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">Cargo</label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt101" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"></label></td></tr><tr class="ui-widget-content" role="row"><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt102" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">Income</label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt103" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"></label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt104" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">Municipality Name</label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt105" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"></label></td></tr><tr class="ui-widget-content" role="row"><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt106" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">State</label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt107" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"></label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt108" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">Neighborhood</label></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label id="tabs:clientListForm:j_idt45:1:j_idt109" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"></label></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>
]]>
</update>
<update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0">
<![CDATA[ -7968619573818716327:7367938744835066462 ]]>
</update>
</changes>
</partial-response>
```

the following is the console error message :

```
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase execute
WARNING: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

- I am using Spring Security/Login.

[Click for the application View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSkzL.jpg)

Comment: The technical answer to your concrete question is http://stackoverflow.com/q/14804452 However, your underlying problem of NullPointerException has to be solved differently depending on its nature. You did not include the full stack trace, so we can't tell why this NPE was thrown. At least, this should be a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10449862

Comment: thank you sir !  it's also very difficult for me to trace it because this problem occur very rarely not all the time , just sometime suddenly i face this problem and then by refreshing the page every thing looks fine.

Comment: but you DO have the full stacktrace in case of a problem, don't you? And you did **not** tag it spring... for a reason? This might very well be cause by an error in the ajax call that makes the spring layer do weird things.

Comment: yes i have the full stacktrace i will include it if i face the same error again and there is no ajax working during accessing the application but just passing through spring security ...

Comment: Is it likely that session has just expired, and that Spring Security has some "remember me" enabled, and that the user is automatically logged-in again, and that Spring Security will thereafter automatically re-execute the originally executed request, however failed to do so properly because it's an ajax request, not a normal request?

Comment: no it's not related to session because mostly this problem occur when i start the server and the application loaded after login when i click on the application so this error occur not every time but some times ..... and if the session get expired then why not it take me to the login page instead of showing the application normally after refreshing the page ..

Comment: An old invalid session that is used after a restart of the server might also cause this in relation tothe BalusC answer

Comment: @kukeltje yes sir you are right ... what would be the possible solution to get rid of this problem ? thanks