# Debug KML: Namespace prefix xsi for schemaLocation on Document is not defined

Tags: debugging, kml, google-earth

I would like to submit the KML file generated by ArcGIS 10.1 and GoogleEarthPRO (GE) as supplementary data for my paper in Elsevier.

However, the reviewer wrote me back: *"here is an error in the prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:schemaLocation”*.

When I tried the simple validation of KML file by adding .xml extension and dropping to Chrome (following: http://kml4earth.appspot.com/kmlBestPractice.html) , I've got an error:

```
error on line 3 at column 217: Namespace prefix xsi for schemaLocation
on Document is not defined
```

I generated the KML by ArcGIS 10.1 (shp to KML, tool: Layer To KML), which produced the zipped .kmz file. I opened the .kmz file in GoogleEarthPRO and again saved my place as .kml file. Apparenly, the .kml file works well as I can open the file in GE and share it between PC.

[image]

I also tried the KMLvalidator here: http://www.kmlvalidator.org/validate.htm with error:

```
File upload request was rejected. (/data/tomcat/base-kml-validator/temp/upload_2a88fa18_1591832a38f__7fff_00001631.tmp (No such file or directory)).
```

I don't understand why my .kml file seems to work fine in GoogleEarthPRO on multiple PCs, but it apparently contains the error in `xsi for schemaLocation`? 
**The most important, what is the easiest way to fix it?**

I am not familiar with scripting the KML code, I am just a beginner and user of GE. Please, how can easily fix my schemaLocation?

File to download: https://www.dropbox.com/s/azmc6m1ksvtau7o/high_tatra_mts.kml?dl=0

Thank you !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Earth generally ignores namespaces and XML elements it doesn't know about so a KML file that is an invalid XML file may still be viewable in Google Earth. To enable error checking in Google Earth, open Tools/Options/General and check the "Show prompts for all errors" option then open your KML file.

If there is a namespace error in your KML file then you need to declare it in KML file - typically in the root element.

Here is the structure of a valid KML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
...
</kml>
```

Note that Google Earth will not fix invalid namespace references in your KML so these must be fixed in a text editor and validated externally to Google Earth.

In your particular example, the xsi declaration and *schemaLocation* attributes are unnecessary so your KML can be simplified to this:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
..
</kml>
```

Comment: thank you @JasonM1. Please, where in my code should I insert the xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> ? is .kml indentation and space specific? Is there a way how to save a correct .kml file from GE without my manual adjustement of coding?

Comment: GE won't add/fix namespaces in your KML. Unbound namespaces remain. Will need to open in text editor and manually add then validate it outside of GE.

Comment: Please, what part of a code should I insert, and where in my code? unfortunatelly, I have not experiences with klm.. please, do I need only to add xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" in my code? please, would you mind to insert it in the correct place in my attached file?

Comment: Hi @JasonM1, I have added the "xmlns:xsi" part of code in my .kml. When I add .xml extension and drop it to Chrome, i get the message: "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below." is this considered as the error too?

Comment: Try to remove the attribute `xsi:schemaLocation="..."` from your original KML file. It is not required.

Comment: I del;eted it and I still have a saying: "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."

Comment: apparently, following this post, I don't need any style sheet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804452/opening-facelets-page-errors-with-this-xml-file-does-not-appear-to-have-any-sty Could that be true?

Comment: Correct. You don't need any style sheets. Try opening XML file with Internet Explorer (IE). Error might be bogus.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134403/discussion-between-jasonm1-and-maycca).

Comment: Just for record, I attach the schema of the valid .kml file: https://developers.google.com/kml/schema/kml21.xsd?csw=1 with missing style information: "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below." Thus I assume this is correct .kml file. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it, I was totally new in .kml