# Avoid direct access to source code of JSF page

Tags: jsf

When I request `/personal/faces/public/login.xhtml`, then it works fine, but when I request `/personal/public/login.xhtml` without `/faces` I obtain the raw source code of the page.

I would like to avoid that people could see the source code of the page. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112946/jsf-link-results-in-plain-xhtml-file-instead-of-generated-jsf-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you've specified `/faces/*` in your `FacesServlet` configuration in the web.xml. As a result, any file requested that does not match the specified url pattern will be served as a regular file with a `GET` request
Change that config to the following to ensure all JSF related requests go through the FacesServlet:

```
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

This ensures **all** files with .xhtml extension will be processed before returning to the client.

While the above solution may solve the immediate problem, what you're experiencing points to a deeper security issue. It indicates that anyone with a browser can request and download artifacts from your web application deployment and possibly other parts of your filesystem. This is a security hole you will need to look into. The options vary depending on your App server

Comment: However, can then add a trailing slash to the URL («path».xthml/) and will still get the source-code (tested in JBoss EAP). So for security you need to configure more than that (or even better stop using JSF legacy).