# jsf bean not working

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

This is my xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Keep alive</title>
    </h:head>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="value" id="value" value="#{myBean.val}" ></f:viewParam>
    </f:metadata>
    <h:body>

        Hello.<h:form><h:outputLabel value="#{myBean.val}"></h:outputLabel></h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And this is my bean:

```
 import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

        import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
        import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;


        @RequestScoped
        @ManagedBean
        public class MyBean {


        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPUhere")
        private EntityManager em;
        /**
         * Creates a new instance of myBean
         */
        public MyBean() {
            System.out.println("mybeanload");
             if (getWaarde() == "yes") {
                System.out.println("IT WORKS!!");
            }

    }
    private String val;

    public String getVal() {
        System.out.println("getting value");
        return val;
    }



     public void setVal(String value) {
            System.out.println("setting value to " + value);
            this.val = value;
        }
}
```

My Bean does not respond to this, what don't I see here? It does not display the value I enter in the URL, nor it displays my outputLabel.

Comment: Rightclick page in browser and do *View Source*. Do you see raw JSF source code, or the JSF-generated HTML output? If you still see the raw JSF source code, then it simply means that the `FacesServlet` is not been invoked at all (because the request URL did not match its URL pattern mapping).

Comment: @BalusC I see <h:form> and stuff - that must be wrong. How can I fix this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15432925/1530938

Answer (score 1):

So, you're retrieving the raw JSF source code in the browser instead of its generated HTML output. Browsers obviously don't understand JSF code (like as it doesn't understand JSP/PHP/ASP/etc code), but it only understands HTML code. This can happen when the `FacesServlet` hasn't been invoked, it's namely the one responsible for all the JSF works.

Perhaps your `FacesServlet` is based on some tutorial or IDE-autogenerated code been mapped on an URL pattern different than `*.xhtml`, such as `*.jsf` or `*.faces`. In that case, you've 2 options:

1. Fix the request URL in your browser's address bar to match exactly that URL pattern. So, assuming that it's `*.jsf`, then don't open the page by

   ```
   http://localhost:8080/context/index.xhtml
   ```

   but instead by

   ```
   http://localhost:8080/context/index.jsf
   ```
2. Fix the URL pattern to be `*.xhtml` directly. This wasn't possible back in JSF 1.x as the `FacesServlet` would otherwise call itself in an infinite loop, but this is quite possible in JSF 2.x and a lot of books/tutorials/resources/IDEs didn't take this into account.

   ```xml
   <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
   ```

#### See also:

- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why/3008504#3008504)

Comment: I was trying it by calling the direct link. The pom.xml contained an automatically generated /faces/* which destroyed everything.

This has been fixed now. Thanks :)