# JSF tags not executed

Tags: jsf

I just started to work with JSF and trying some example implementation.
I got the following Bean, web.xml and index.xhtml files:

HelloBean.java:

```
package jsflearning;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.*;

@Named(value= "myHelloBean")
@RequestScoped
public class HelloBean {
    private String name = "dear reader";

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

    <display-name>JSFLearning</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

index.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<head>
<title>Simplest JSF Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
    <br />
    <h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{myHelloBean.name}"/>
    </h:form>
    <br />
    Hello to you. #{myHelloBean.name} !
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `#{myHelloBean.name}` expression is correctly executed but the `<h:form>`tag is not interpreted and no editbox displayed. Can't find the solution for this problem.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/*` XML namespace is only supported since JSF 2.2. Your problem symptoms suggest that you're still using JSF 2.0 or 2.1.

You've 2 options:

1. Upgrade JSF libraries to a JSF 2.2 compatible version.
2. Downgrade XML namespace to a JSF 2.0/2.1 compatible `http://java.sun.com/jsf/*`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

I did change the XML namespace to `http://java.sun.com/jsf/*` to make a downgrade and support JSF 2.0/2.1.

Sadly the <h:form></h:form> JSF tag is still not displayed.

Comment: Which JSF impl/version are you using then?

Comment: That's spec version. I was asking for impl (Mojarra or MyFaces) and its version (e.g. Mojarra 2.2.10 or MyFaces 2.2.7). Regardless, how does generated HTML output look like?

Comment: I'm using myfaces-api-2.0.24-xxx

Comment: Uh, that's the browser rendering/presentation. With generated HTML output I mean the HTML source code which is (supposed to be) produced by JSF, as you can find by rightclick and *View Source* in the average browser.

Comment: Thx for your patience. The HTML source sode looks like this:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11-transitional.dtd" >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/*">
<head>
<title>Simplest JSF Page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div align="center">
 <br />
 <h:form>
 <h:inputText value="dear reader"></h:inputText>
 </h:form>
 <br />
 Hello to you. dear reader !
  </div>
<div id="javax_faces_developmentstage_messages"></div></body>
</html>

Comment: Hmm, it appears that you don't understand the significance of the wildcard character `*` in developer's terms and that you took my answer literally :/ You should be using `http://java.sun.com/jsf/html` for HTML taglib and `http://java.sun.com/jsf/core` for the core taglib, etc..etc.. It's all about the URI prefix.

Comment: @BalusC the `xmlns.jcp.org` host should be used for all tag libs if I want the newest version instead of `java.sun.com` ? I thought they referenced the same version