# spring-boot + JSF. Views *.jsf working properly but *.xhtml not

Tags: jsf, tomcat, primefaces, spring-boot

I'm using spring boot with jsf (primefaces). [here](https://github.com/bilak/spring-boot-primefaces-template) you can find sample of my application. When I invoke this application using `mvn spring-boot:run` and access application [with jsf](http://localhost:8080/view/fileupload.jsf) or [with xhtml](http://localhost:8080/view/fileupload.xhtml) everything works ok. But when I deploy this application to tomcat, xhtml page is not rendered properly. I can see page source (xhtml source, not html), but this is not wanted. I want to be able to **display the same** with **.jsf** and **.xhtml**.

Can anybody tell me what am I missing?

Edit:

as I reviewd [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112946/jsf-returns-blank-page-with-plain-raw-xhtml-xml-source-instead-of-rendered-html) issue and it was not helpfull (I also have *.xhtml mapping for faces servlet and as I wrote before, this is working on spring-boot embedded tomcat but not on classic tomcat), I think the problem will be more related to the spring configuration, but I'm not sure what and where to change.

Thanks

Comment: I think problem will be somewhere in spring config not in jsf. As I said, in spring-boot application it's working ok.

Comment: You need to include your servlet mapping and spring boot configuration in the post, otherwise we won't be able to help you...

Answer (score 0):

Problem in spring config. Add this to file Application.java:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/view/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".xhtml");
    return resolver;
}
```