# Facelets error page works during ajax request with FullAjaxExceptionHandler, but does not evaluate EL during synchronous request

Tags: jsf, error-handling, web.xml, omnifaces

I am trying to configure a normal (non-ajax) request error page using Omnifaces library. I am able to use the FullAjaxExceptionHandler and with ajax request error and its page as shown in the demo. When I use the same error page with normal request the error page is shown, but the values are displayed as source code (for example Date/time: #{of:formatDate(now, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')} User agent: #{header['user-agent']} .. are displayed in the browser as it is).

I am using Tomcat 7, JSF 2.2 (MyFaces), Weld 2.6 (for CDI), Omnifaces 2.0 and Primefaces 5.1. The following is the relevant code.

The page:

```
<h:commandButton value="Throw runtime exception on normal request"      
    action="#{appbean.throwRuntimeException}"/>

<p:commandButton value="Throw runtime exception on AJAX request"        
    action="#{appbean.throwRuntimeException}"/>
```

The bean:

```
public void throwRuntimeException() {
        throw new RuntimeException("peek-a-boo");
}
```

faces-config:

```
<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>
        org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory  
    </exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>facesExceptionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.FacesExceptionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>facesExceptionFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.RuntimeException</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/error2.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: So, your faces servlet is not mapped on the URL pattern of `*.xhtml`?

Comment: and how is this PrimeFaces related?

Comment: @ Kukeltje I was also testing the error page with an ajax call also. There is a p:commandButton in the page. I did not show it for brevity. I will edit the page code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<error-page><location>` must match the `FacesServlet` mapping in order to get `FacesServlet` to run on the error page too during an exception on a synchronous request (which doesn't use [`ViewHandler#renderView()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandler.html#restoreView(javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String)), but [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse))).

Alter the mapping accordingly:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Using `/faces/*` (and `*.faces`) is soo JSF 1.0/1.1. If you really need to keep `/faces/*` for some reason (e.g. existing webapp with already published URLs), then just use both (and migrate with 301s accordingly):

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

#### See also:

- [JSF returns blank/unparsed page with plain/raw XHTML/XML/EL source instead of rendered HTML output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112946/jsf-returns-blank-unparsed-page-with-plain-raw-xhtml-xml-el-source-instead-of-re)