# How to force .jsf file extension when .xhtml is typed directly in url

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, url-rewriting, glassfish, file-extension

When using JSF, one can choose from several extensions like:

1. /faces/*
2. *.jsf
3. *.xhtml

Where the last one is recommended for JSF 2.2 at least.
But what if I wanted to use the  `.jsf` extension, I get a problem here is that if someone were to type out of "curiosity" `.xhtml` then weird stuff could start to happen if you for example mix JSF tags with normal HTML tags.

So I know that GlassFish server's Admin Console for example forces the URL rewrite to `.jsf` if I type `.xhtml`, how can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Simply restrict direct access to `.xhtml` files in `web.xml`.

   ```xml
   <security-constraint>
       <display-name>Restrict direct access to XHTML files</display-name>
       <web-resource-collection>
           <web-resource-name>XHTML files</web-resource-name>
           <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
       </web-resource-collection>
       <auth-constraint />
   </security-constraint>
   ```

   See also [JSF returns blank/unparsed page with plain/raw XHTML/XML/EL source instead of rendered HTML output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112946/jsf-returns-blank-unparsed-page-with-plain-raw-xhtml-xml-el-source-instead-of-re).
2. Create a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which listens on `*.xhtml` and redirects to `*.jsf`.

   ```
   @WebFilter("*.xhtml")
   public class FacesUrlRewriteFilter implements Filter {

       @Override
       public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
           HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
           HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

           String redirectURI = request.getRequestURI().replaceAll("xhtml$", "jsf");
           String queryString = request.getQueryString();

           if (queryString != null) {
               redirectURI += "?" + queryString;
           }

           response.sendRedirect(redirectURI);
       }

       // ...
   }
   ```

   See also [How to use a servlet filter in Java to change an incoming servlet request url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725102/how-to-use-a-servlet-filter-in-java-to-change-an-incoming-servlet-request-url)

Comment: Actually what I meant with the GlassFish URL rewrite was that the admin console forces all xhtml to jsf, I guess I needed to specify more but thank you.

Comment: Yes, I should have specified more on this.