# How to add JSF Implementation Libraries?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, apache-tomee

I'm using TomEE. I was under impression that TomEE already has the `JSF IMplementation Libraries`.

So when create an Eclipse project, I follow the documentation and choose [Library Provided By Target Runtime](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.jsf.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Freference%2Fjsf_library_management.html)

[image]

It reads `this facet requires jsf implementation library to be present on project classpath. By disabling library configuration, user takes on responsibility of configuring classpath appropriately via alternate means`

So I go ahead and add all the bundled jars that come with TomEE `...\apache-tomee-webprofile-1.7.4\lib` (this includes `myfaces-api-2.1.17.jar` and `myfaces-impl-2.1.17.jar`)

---

Then I `Run on Server` the following test `xhtml` . **But it renders a blank page.** Obviously, the `xhtml` was not compiled. So the bundled TomEE jars did NOT kick in. How can I make those bundled TomEE jars compile my test `xhtml` ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">

    <h:head>
        <title>Hello World - Input Form</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h:form>
            <h:inputText id="name" value="#{theUserName}" 
                            a:placeholder="What's your name?" />

            <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="myresponse" />
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: You said yourself, TomEE already provides JSF libraries, why exactly are you still selecting "User Library" instead of "Library provided by Target Runtime"?

Comment: @BalusC Because Eclipse does NOT compile `xhtml` unless I download `JSF` libraries

Comment: I added the detailed explanation. I understand that the test xhtml was simply not compiled . The `JSF` tags were not interpreted correctly . This can only happen if the `JSF` libraries did not kick in to interpret the tags

Comment: Is your blank page problem answered here? http://stackoverflow.com/q/3112946 If JSF libraries were not found, you'd get ClassNotFoundException on FacesServlet instead and the webapp deployment would block altogether.

Comment: @BalusC Thank you very much. Just as you said the answer is there `change the <url-pattern> from /faces/* to *.xhtml`

Comment: It is a duplicate. I'm not sure if I should delete it. Please let me know

Comment: Duplicates make search engines happy with new keywords. Deletions account towards question ban threshold.

Answer (score 1):

TomEE has MyFaces as JSF implementation in tomee/lib folder. Worse case add it referencing myfaces-api there but ensure to not put it in the war during packaging.

Comment: Thank you . I tried doing exactly as you recommend. I provided more details.