# JSF Bootsfaces components not showing

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

Today I was working on our application for a school project. We had no problems with the our Bootsfaces but suddenly I can't seem to get the components to show (see image). I don't know what's causing this unexpected behaviour because it worked before. Nothing has been changed to the .xhtml page. The error log in the Chrome console and the Payara console are both giving 0 errors.

I am using Payara 5.181 and Java EE 7.

**Edit:**

Removing the "generated" folder in the Payara server and restarting the PC seems to solve this problem, but after a while (can't reproduce exactly why) the page turns blank again.

[image: Screenshot of the page]

**.xhtml file**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Kies je cartracker</title>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="default.css" library="css" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1>Kies je cartracker:</h1>
        <b:dataTable value="#{tourmanager.allCartrackers}" 
                     var="tracker">
            <b:dataTableColumn>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Vehicle" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{tracker.vehicle.serieNr}" />
            </b:dataTableColumn>
            <b:dataTableColumn>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Kies cartracker" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:form>
                    <b:commandButton action="#{tourmanager.pickCartracker(tracker)}"
                                   value="Pick car" >
                    </b:commandButton>
                </h:form>
            </b:dataTableColumn>
        </b:dataTable>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.bootsfaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootsfaces</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Try `<h:form><d:dataTable..>..</b:dataTable></h:form>` (without nesting the form)

Comment: @JasperdeVries This does not work unfortunately.. It shows the same empty page.

Comment: What is the welcome page in the web.xml? Is it mapped to `index.jsf`? Does it work if you add `index.jsf` to the URL in the browser?

Comment: @JasperdeVries We are using the following code: `<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>pickCartracker.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>` to redirect to the homepage. It does not work when I link to `http://localhost:8080/RegistrationSystem/pickCartracker.xhtml`

Comment: Then change `<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSF returns blank/unparsed page with plain/raw XHTML/XML/EL source instead of rendered HTML output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112946/jsf-returns-blank-unparsed-page-with-plain-raw-xhtml-xml-el-source-instead-of-re)

Comment: @JasperdeVries Do you have any idea why it worked before though?

Comment: Maybe you were using different URL's in the browser (ending in `.jsf`)

Comment: With modern JSF these entries in the web.xml are not needed anymore...

Comment: @JasperdeVries It just worked, and I reployed again and I'm getting the same problem again. Any idea's?

Comment: Just restarted my pc and removed everything from the "generated" directory in the payara server and it worked again.. I don't get it

Comment: Why a bounty? It was solved, right?

Comment: @JasperdeVries The problem keeps re-appearing. Sometimes deleting the "generated" directory in the payara server and restarting my PC fixes the issue (but not always).. It's pretty weird

Comment: Please update your question to what exactly is happening and what your current configuration exactly is.

Answer (score 1):

curiously in my case I had a similar problem, and it turns out that so many modifications and tests prove that this dependency in my pom.xml generated that the bootsfaces components were not rendered. My solution was to eliminate this dependence.

org.glassfishjavax.faces2.2.7