# Issues setting up PrimeFaces with RAD/Websphere

Tags: primefaces, websphere, ibm-rad

I have been using RAD/WebSphere successfully with the default JSF library but am going to be working on a project that uses PrimeFaces..I have downloaded the jar file and went to the buildpath and added the external jar. I do have the tags right in my code, I believe, as it is the test code from the PrimeFaces website documentation.

I have downloaded the jar file and went to the buildpath and added the external jar. I do have the tags right in my code, I believe, as it is the test code from the PrimeFaces website documentation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
<title>index</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <p:spinner />
    </h:body>

</html>
```

The file runs blank but with no errors. I can run other files on the localhost server that work fine. Everything I found on how to fix it says to just add the jar file via the build classpath and it should work. The webpage loads no errors but the "problems" view in RAD says the Jar file will not be exported of published. What am I missing?

Comment: did you do a 'view-source' of the html in the client? What did it show?

Comment: Yes the part with the PrimeFaces tag showed:
`<p:inputText></p:inputText>
 
   <h3>Floating Label</h3>
   <span class="ui-float-label">
       <p:inputText value=""></p:inputText>
       <p:outputLabel value="Username"></p:outputLabel>
   </span><input type="hidden" name="j_id2059540600_7ac21836_SUBMIT" value="1" /><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="PoQ6IKlUIHbeBOULjRQ1F/nKFFtvM+WRDgkw7EnnItiwiEn7hbBsC0FihrWLqkU4AvtGYvqbBt/TnRdp8PzCPYhPOIyhiOephBBCqemIFNMPh85b316sRdQ6QGI=" /></form><div id="javax_faces_developmentstage_messages">`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSF returns blank/unparsed page with plain/raw XHTML/XML/EL source instead of rendered HTML output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112946/jsf-returns-blank-unparsed-page-with-plain-raw-xhtml-xml-el-source-instead-of-re)