# Primefaces menu and model doesn't show

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi I'm trying to create a Programmatic menu and I'm using the primefaces [example](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menu.xhtml) but when I deploy the server doesn't show, any idea
I'm using tomcat v8.5 and Primefaces 7.0

```
public class MenuBean {
private MenuModel model;

public MenuBean() {
    //Add menus and submenus
}
public MenuModel getModel() { 
    return model;
 }
}
```

the xhtml file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags">
<h:head>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:event listener="#{foo.loadUserSession}"
            type="preRenderView" />
    </f:metadata>
</h:head>
    <h:form>
        <b:row>

            <p:menu model="#{menuBean.model}" />
        </b:row>

    </h:form>
   </ui:composition>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSF returns blank/unparsed page with plain/raw XHTML/XML/EL source instead of rendered HTML output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112946/jsf-returns-blank-unparsed-page-with-plain-raw-xhtml-xml-el-source-instead-of-re)

Comment: And don't mix jsf namespaces...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the tags to your class?
Did you initiated MenuModel model?

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class MenuBean {

    private MenuModel model;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        model = new DefaultMenuModel();
    }

    public MenuModel getModel() { 
        return model;
    }
}
```

Probably that's why it isn't showing when you start.

Comment: If this was missing you would have gotten an exception