# JSF tags (xHTML) are not rendered as HTML on browser

Tags: spring-boot, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to do JSF Primefaces with spring boot
HTML pages works fine.

but the xHTML pages, does not get rendered as HTML. if I do F12 on my browser, I see the JSF tags.

I have look at:
[JSF returns blank/unparsed page with plain/raw XHTML/XML/EL source instead of rendered HTML output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112946/jsf-returns-blank-unparsed-page-with-plain-raw-xhtml-xml-el-source-instead-of-re)

- I see the URL matches FacesServlet mapping: look at my Web.xml below
- The that XML namespaces are for JSF 2.2:  look at my Web.xml and webpage below

I am not too sure about the last one:

> "Multiple JSF implementations have been loaded"

In my library I see "Maven: org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:2.3.3" and "Maven: org.glassfish:jakarta.el:3.0.3" as well as tomcat. I did not add either, and I am not able from the project structure in IntelliJ IDE remove them:
Here is my pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>caom.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>motive</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>TestApp</name>
    <description>Motive WebApp for Propositom project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
        <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>
        <jsf.version>2.2.8</jsf.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.18.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.18.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is my Web.xML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="4.0"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/WebPage/Welcome.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                                  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd" version="2.2">

</faces-config>
```

Here is my webpage

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">

<ui:composition template="/templates/WebPageTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="pageTitle" value="Home"/>
    <ui:define name="Header">
        <title> home | Motive</title>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="MainBody">
        <h3><strong>This is HTML</strong></h3>
        <p>And it is sowing</p>
        <h:outputText value="This is JSF, and it is not sowing"/>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

I have even recreated the project just in case I had some hidden miss-configuration.

**If you don't know the answer, but can point me to a good tutorial on how to set this up, or even how to trace the rendering. that Will be great!!!**

Comment: Checkout http://joinfaces.org/ that project provides integration of JSF with Spring Boot

Comment: What application server are you using?

Comment: If I understand your question properly, I did not specify one, so Think it will be tomcat.
This is package as a jar and not a war

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I ended up removing the WEB-INF and using JoinFaces 4.3
here is a github like to a sample code:

[JoinfacesExample](https://github.com/Guilderm/JoinfacesExample)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your template

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
```

and this to your webpage.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                template="/templates/WebPageTemplate.xhtml">
```

also try to change path template="**/WEB-INF/templates/WebPageTemplate.xhtml**"

I don't know if this will solve your case, it can be caused by many factors.