# Running primefaces on java spring

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

I used JSF with PrimeFaces very long time ago for class purposes.

Right now I want to get into spring and build a website for myself where I dont get any support for.

Usually what I want to do should be straight forward but somehow I dont really get what I done wrong, as  - if im not mistaken - It should be just 1 dependency and the .html itself.

I added into the **pom.xml**

```java
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I created a **test2.html** file:

```java
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <p:spinner />
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The outcome looks like this:
[image: My website]

So my question is: Why dont the spinner gets shown on the test2.html site itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSF returns blank/unparsed page with plain/raw XHTML/XML/EL source instead of rendered HTML output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112946/jsf-returns-blank-unparsed-page-with-plain-raw-xhtml-xml-el-source-instead-of-re)

Comment: Try using `.xhtml` instead of `.html`, and also take a look at http://joinfaces.org/

Comment: @stefan-dan depends on the JSF servlet configuration. See duplicate.

Comment: I can't recommend JoinFaces enough if you really want to do Spring Boot + JSF.